# PDF viewer in chromium?

Tags: chromium, pdf, plugins

Google Chrome has plugin to view pdf files inside the browser.

Is there any plugin for chromium which can do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you have Google Chrome installed? If you do have it installed, you can just make a link to the ***libpdf.so*** plugin in the Chromium folder:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/google/chrome/libpdf.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/
```

After that, enter `about:plugins` in Chromium, search for `Chrome PDF Viewer` and enable it.

If you don't have Google Chrome already installed, I suggest you to download the ***.deb***  package and extract it. Then, you must navigate to the folder `data/opt/google/chrome` and copy the ***libpdf.so*** to the `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/`. [More details](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/07/use-google-chrome%E2%80%99s-native-pdf-reader-in-chromium).

Comment: @madox2: I'm glad it worked `:)`

Comment: remember to restart chromium for the libpdf.so to take effect.

Comment: or you could install the pdf.js extension [Chrome Web Store - PDF Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm)